# To solve Laplace's equation on the semiplane $z>0$ and consider $f(x,y,0) = V_0$ a constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The physics forum is not the most dynamic.

Puns apart, I want to solve Laplace's differential equation $\nabla^2f =0$ in the $\mathbb R^3$ with the boundary condition that $f(x,y,0) = V_0$.

$f:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ countinuously differentiable in the both semi planes $z>0$ and $z<0$.

To find the potential in the whole charge-free space when the potential in the plane $z=0$ is a constant $V_0$.

I did some physics calculations with the Green Functions and I got that $f(x,y,z) = V_0$ for all $x,y,z$.
I would like a confirmation/correction of this result.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/551823/is-it-the-case-that-if-we-have-an-equipotential-infinite-plane-in-charge-free-sp

I believe the separation of variables can verify this result.

Comment: $V_0 + a z$ is also a solution

Comment: yes but the potential in infinity would also go to infinity if $a \neq 0$

Comment: Yup. I dont remember enough physics terminology to know if you already accounted for that in your post (sorry). Your constant function is indeed a solution as can be verified by direct computation of $\nabla^2 V_0$

Comment: I believe (but i'm also not sure) they assume the potential on infinity to be zero when they came up with the formula I used.